# How to edit Wordpress Twenty Seventeen: Homepage (front-page.php) so it only shows a snippet of content

Tags: php, wordpress

My client's site crashed and she's currently relying on the default WordPress theme until she finds a new one

In the meantime, I still want her to have a website that's user-friendly. Here's the problem: the theme allows you to add front page sections and it pulls from pages that are already created, but it doesn't allow you to modify how much of that page is shown. I have around 500 words on these pages for SEO purposes, but I don't want to create a messy front page that's clogged up with all of this information. Instead, I just want to pull a snippet of information.

Is there a way to do this?
Here's the code:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Displays content for front page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'twentyseventeen-panel ' ); ?> >

 <?php
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
  $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );

  // Calculate aspect ratio: h / w * 100%.
  $ratio = $thumbnail[2] / $thumbnail[1] * 100;
  ?>

  <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>);">
   <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: <?php echo esc_attr( $ratio ); ?>%"></div>
  </div><!-- .panel-image -->

 <?php endif; ?>

 <div class="panel-content">
  <div class="wrap">
   <header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>

    <?php twentyseventeen_edit_link( get_the_ID() ); ?>

   </header><!-- .entry-header -->

   <div class="entry-content">
    <?php
     /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
     the_content(
      sprintf(
       __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentyseventeen' ),
       get_the_title()
      )
     );
    ?>
   </div><!-- .entry-content -->

  </div><!-- .wrap -->
 </div><!-- .panel-content -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: Welcome. To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting for that in WordPress.
Just select (in the backend): Settings > Reading > For each article in a feed, show > Summary

Comment: Hi. I tried doing that, but it didn't work. Maybe it's because I'm pulling from pages and not blog posts. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Hi! Can you show me the content of the content-front-page.php file? It should be located under template-parts/page/ ...

Comment: Couldn't insert the code you're looking for into this comment, so I've edited my original post and added it in there. Again, thanks for the help!